# How to make Monodevelop and F# work

Tags: f#, monodevelop

I have VS 2010 + NET 4 on my pc. I downloaded F# bindings for Monodevelop and Monodevelop 2.8.6.4 for Windows.

> https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding
>
> http://monodevelop.com/Download

I ran `install.bat` which copied `FSharpBinding.dll` and `FSharpBinding.Gui.dll` to `c:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\BackendBindings\`.

I opened new Solution in Monodevelop but there is no F# solution there. Do you know what is the next step I should do to make F# work with Monodevelop? I also checked add-in manager but I did not see any F# bindings installed there.

Comment: Dumb question I guess but have you seen this information: http://functional-variations.net/monodevelop/ and have you worked through it?

Comment: I confirm that this no longer works with new Mono/MonoDevelop since it hasn't been updated for a while. That's why OP has to compile *fsharpbinding* from source and install it manually.

Comment: @pad I thought that was the case; I wish Xamarin would support the F# language bindings as part of the whole MonoDevelop package.

Comment: @Onorio: that would be fantastic. Fsharp would grow its user base if people found it easy to use with MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember, the official *fsharpbinding* doesn't work with Mono 2.8 onwards. This is [a fork](https://github.com/karthikvishnu/fsharpbinding) which seems to work with new Mono versions.

However, you didn't mention you have installed Mono or not. If you do so, make sure that you install Mono 10.x since they include F# compiler in their installation already.

If Monodevelop recognizes *fsharpbinding* correctly, you will see F# solution in the list of solutions and F# binding installed in add-in manager.

Comment: Yes, I suppose. I have used *fsharpbinding* with Mono, but have no experience using *fsharpbinding* and .NET framework.

Comment: So I have installed Mono 2.10.8, downloaded the fork you suggested and ran `install.bat`. However, I am still not able to see any F# solution

Comment: There are two things to check: 1, Does Monodevelop use Mono as .NET runtimes (see Option -> .NET runtimes)? 2, Were *fsharpbinding* files installed in `AddIns\BackendBindings` in *Monodevelop* root directory?

Comment: I changed the default .NET runtimes into Mono but the Monodevelop still insists that "Monodevelop is currently running on Microsoft.NET". Is that a problem? The `fsharpbinding` dlls are in the `BackendBindings` folder. Still I cannot make it work...

Comment: The message is strange; that could be the problem. Usually after changing .NET runtimes and restarting Monodevelop, it will not complain. As a last resort, you could try to install add-in from files in add-in manager.

Comment: It sounds stupid, but you can uninstall Monodevelop, delete their cache files and install it again. I usually install Mono before Monodevelop in any case.

Comment: By erasing several hint paths in the `FSharp.MonoDevelop.fsproj`, I made it work, but still I am having issues with the debugging and real-time type checking. But at least I made a little step further :)

Comment: Good to know, MonoDevelop is now using Mono as .NET runtimes, isn't it?

Comment: No. It is still using Microsoft .NET. I have read that it is probably impossible to switch it into Mono. Anyway, I would prefer to make it working with .NET 4. I will update this topic if / when I will make it fully work with .NET 4